# Servicestack converting timezone from UTC to any timezone

Tags: c#, .net-core, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have read you don't have support for this. But I want to make sure I am not missing something.

We have several cases where we need to convert the saved UTC dates into other timezones. During a query it would be nice to automatically convert from UTC to a specific timezone on load. On save convert from timezone a to UTC.  I know normally you would do this in the UI. But we have cases where users will call the API and ask for a CSV and we need it to convert.  Does anyone know if this is possible in servicestack. Maybe with a JSConfig value or a data validator?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible in ServiceStack, but you could use [AutoMapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) and create a simple adapter to convert the representation in the database (UTC) to the representation for the client.

Pseudo-code:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime FooDate { get; set; }
}

public static class TimeZoneAdapter
{
    public Foo Map(Foo foo)
    {
        var map = Mapper.Map(foo);
        map.FooDate = ConvertToLocalDateTime(map.FooDate);
        return map;
    }
}

// Use Map on the database objects.
var q = db.From<Foo>().Select(x => TimeZoneAdapter.Map(x));

List<Foo> results = db.Column<Foo>(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `DateTime` only supports [Utc, Local, Unspecified DateTime Kinds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=netframework-4.8) so there's no way to represent a specific TimeZone in a `DateTime` property which doesn't capture TimeZone information, you would need to change the actual DateTime value and specify to use an `Unspecified` DateTimeKind since using anything else would be a lie.

The [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime) built-in struct does let you capture a TimeZone offset with the DateTime value, which you would use if you need to need to store a DateTime in addition to a specific TimeZone offset.

But I'd recommend against trying to configure the Serializer with this custom App Serialization logic. Apply this logic in a post processing step like in a custom Mapper as @Dennis1679 suggests. ServiceStack.Text does support .NET's DataContract's custom hooks is another option for running custom logic before / after serialization, e.g:

```
public class SerializationHooksExamples
{
    /// Will be executed when deserializing starts
    [OnDeserializing]
    protected void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        //...
    }

    /// Will be executed when deserializing finished
    [OnDeserialized]
    protected void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        //...
    }

    /// Will be executed when serializing starts
    [OnSerializing]
    protected void OnSerializing(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        //...
    }

    /// Will be executed when serializing finished
    [OnSerialized]
    protected void OnSerialized(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```